# How to convert strings in a list into list, to from[[list1],[list2]....[listm]]

Tags: python

I have some data like:
['6005,280', '6005,2751', '6005,260']

and I want to convert them into a list like:
[['6005','280'],['6005','2751'],['6005','260']]

I use

```
for i in range(len(mainText)):
    target_list.append(int(x) for x in mainText[i].split(','))
```

But got some crazy output like:

```
[<generator object main.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000000DA61784C78>, <generator object main.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000000DA61784B10>, <generator object main.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000000DA61784CF0>]
```

So what is the correct way to do that?

Code:

```
import csv

def main():
    inputfile=open('price.csv','r')
    mainText=mainPart(inputfile)
##    print(mainText)
    target_list=[]
    for i in range(len(mainText)):
        target_list.append(int(x) for x in mainText[i].split(','))
    print(target_list)




def mainPart(file):
    ## import items with first row
    rowsWithEnter1=[row for row in file]
    ## del first row
    rowsWithEnter2=rowsWithEnter1[1:]
    rows=[]
    for i in range(len(rowsWithEnter2)):
        rows.append(rowsWithEnter2[i].strip('\n'))
    return rows

main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a comprehension (like `int(x) for x in ...`) inside parentheses, it is  interpreted as a generator, which is a special type of object which can then be iterated over to produce a list. The crazy output you're seeing is because you've actually created a list of generators, instead of a list of lists. To interpret your comprehensions as lists instead of generators, you just need to put them in square brackets:

```
for i in range(len(mainText)):
    target_list.append([int(x) for x in mainText[i].split(',')])
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve what I think you want is the following:

```
mainText = ['6005,280', '6005,2751', '6005,260']
target_list = [elem.split(',') for elem in mainText]
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension should work:

```
[x.split(',') for x in mainText]
```

Answer (score 1):

A less preferable alternative to [@francisco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51899140/2988730):

```
list(map(str.split, mainText))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way using list comprehension

`l = ['6005,280', '6005,2751', '6005,260']
[list(item.split(',')) for item in l]`

Comment: Why are you applying `list` to something guaranteed to be a list, only to convert it back into a string (which is not what OP wants)?

Comment: quoting from the OP it appears he wants his output to be a list of lists [['6005','280'],['6005','2751'],['6005','260']]. I originally thought he had quotations around the inner lists